# Hyper-V Start-VM stuck on "Connecting to..."

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I want to start a VM from command line (running win server 2016),
but I found that the command `Start-VM` will cause the VM stuck on "Connecting to...",
the preview screen always shows black.
[image]

**Until** I opened the VM (double click on its name in Manager), it starts installing and works fine.
(It shows "connecting to" in the beginning.)

[image]

**I can start the VM perfectly via Hyper-V Manager, but I can't start it using command line `Start-VM`. Why? How to solve this problem? Any help is appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use CMD but Use powershell and type

Start-VM -Name "virtual machine name"

Comment: I am using powershell, but `-Name` did the trick for me, although it still has another problem, thanks!